# How to find a conditional solution of inequalities?

Tags: equation-solving, inequalities, code

Im trying to find the conditions of:

```
a>0,b>0,c>1,d>0
(a + (2 a - b/c) d + (a + b - b/c) d^2 + (-b + (2 b)/c) d^3 + (b d^4)/
   c - (b d^5)/c) > 0
```

I use this code:

```
Reduce[{(a + (2 a - b/c) d + (a + b - b/c) d^2 + (-b + (2 b)/
        c) d^3 + (b d^4)/c - (b d^5)/c) > 0, b > 0, c > 1, a > 0, 
  d > 0}, {a,b}, Reals]
```

Is there better way to find the conditions

Thanks

Comment: Maybe try `Simplify[Reduce[{(a+(2a-b/c)d+(a+b-b/c)d^2+(-b+(2b)/c)d^3+(b d^4)/c-(b d^5)/c)>0,b>0,c>1,a>0,d>0},{a,b}],b>0&&c>1&&a>0&&d>0]` Because you told it each var>0 it knows those must be Real without needing to tell it Real and that often seems to make  Reduce faster. Then Simplify will remove the constraints you already know, making the ones that remain easier to see and understand. Be careful using that.

Answer (score 1):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

cons[1] = 
  Reduce[{(a + (2 a - b/c) d + (a + b - 
          b/c) d^2 + (-b + (2 b)/c) d^3 + (b d^4)/c - (b d^5)/c) > 0, b > 0, 
    c > 1, a > 0, d > 0}, {a, b}, Reals];
```

To reduce the `LeafCount` use simplification

```
cons[2] = cons[1] // Simplify;

cons[3] = cons[1] // FullSimplify;
```

To eliminate the `Root` expressions while reducing the `LeafCount` (but with increased `LeafCount` compared with just simplification) use both `ToRadicals` and `Simplify`

```
cons[4] = cons[1] // ToRadicals // Simplify;

FreeQ[cons[4], _Root]

(* True *)
```

However, if `FullSimplify` is used, the `Root` expressions are reintroduced.

```
cons[5] = cons[1] // ToRadicals // FullSimplify;

FreeQ[cons[5], _Root]

(* False *)
```

Comparing `LeafCount`

```
LeafCount /@ (cons /@ Range[5])

(* {314, 231, 228, 277, 230} *)
```

The different constraints describe the same region

```
Clear[rgn]; 
Evaluate[rgn /@ Range[5]] = ImplicitRegion[#, {a, b, c, d}] & /@
  (cons /@ Range[5]);

RegionEqual @@ (rgn /@ Range[5])

(* True *)
```